# looking for a C# or .Net based Acceptance testing framework - alternative to Aqua or Robot

Tags: .net, acceptance-testing

We have extensive system tests written in the Python based Robot framework, and some in the Java based Aqua framework.
Robot is flexible and has good logging, but is quite cumbersome, and Aqua also didn't raise much enthusiasm with the people who used it here.
the product tested is mostly C#/.Net based, and we are looking for a solid extensive framework that will enable us to easily initialize VMs and manipulate them (using SSH/telnet), define the steps, waits etc, and also enjoy static typing - so we don't need to run for a few hours before we find some parameter at some test step wasn't right.

we could develop an in-house solution, either from scratch or base it on NUnit/Fitnesse (we have a good experience with both for unittesting/fit tests, but they don't supply much logging/Telnet/SSH capabilities)

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 6):

[Disclosure: I'm the lead developer of Robot Framework]

Would you be interested in enhancing Robot Framework [1] so that it supports you needs better? We don't currently support .NET fully, but we've tested that it is possible to run the framework on it using IronPython. Full .NET support, including an ability to implement test libraries using C#, would be really cool, and we have an enhancement request open about it [2]. Unfortunately the core development team works in an environment where .NET isn't that important, and we thus need help from someone who has more .NET/IronPython experience.

Please also submit enhancement requests about the "cumbersome" issues to the issue tracker. Hopefully we can fix some of them or help you to create patches. In general I believe you'd get better ROI making and existing tool better than implementing something from scratch.

[1] http://robotframework.org
[2] http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/issues/detail?id=154

Comment: interesting idea, however the company already decided to go for an in house solution - writing tests and adding required features in an agile manner as they are needed (hope this doesn't sound too "new age"). but I might try to look into robot over IronPython since it sounds interesting.
I will try to gather some feedback and see if there's anything worth reporting to the robot issue tracker.

Comment: Adding full .NET support for RF ought to be a relatively simple task. There are some open questions related to installation, C# support, etc. but I don't expect them to be blockers. Let us know if you are interested to help!

Comment: Darn that appeared in the wrong place: Pekka - I'm happy to help answer questions if the offer is still open.

Cheers Mark

Comment: Robot Framework's .NET support has gotten better recently. The steps to get you started are here: http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/DotNetSupport

Comment: If RobotFramework's .NET support isn't a good option, there is now another alternative to use native C# via remote library interface to Robot Framework, removing need to use or write wrapper library with IronPython. http://code.google.com/p/sharprobotremoteserver/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Avignon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avignon/) framework.

Comment: thanks for the tip. it seems to be more of a web-oriented testing framework though, isn't it? (although it may perform well also for other usages, I haven't looked deep enough yet)